# How can I show Nfts minted in other contracts in my NFT Marketplace?

Tags: javascript, erc-721, ethereumjs, polygon, erc-1155

I want to create a NFT Marketplace website where people can list and buy NFTs. It will be multi-chain supporting both Polygon and Ethereum chains. It will accept both ERC721 & ERC1155 tokens.

I want to know **how can I list those tokens in my website if I don't know there contract abi?**

Is there any way by which I can get the contract's abi from the contract's address so that I can call the methods of the NFT contracts?

This is my code where I tried to do the above:-

```
async function getAllNFTs() {
        const key = simpleCrypto.decrypt(cipherEth);
        const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(mainnet);
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(key, provider);
        const signer = wallet.provider.getSigner(wallet.address);
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(EMNMarketAddress, EMNMarket, signer);
        
        const data = await contract.getAvailableNft();

        const items = await data.map(async i => {
            const tokenContract = i.nftContract.toString();
            console.log(tokenContract);
            const tokenUri = await tokenContract.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
            const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri)
            let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(i.price.toString(), 'ether')
            let item = {
                price,
                tokenId: i.tokenId.toNumber(),
                seller: i.seller,
                owner: i.owner,
                image: meta.data.image,
                name: meta.data.name,
                description: meta.data.description,
            }
            return item
        })

        setNfts(items);
        setLoadingState('loaded');
    }
```

It is giving me the following error:-

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tokenContract.tokenURI is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract ABI should be one that covers ERC721 and ERC1155. My approach to an nft martketplace is this one?

```
function setDirectSell(address _NFT, uint _tokenID, uint _price) external isOwner(_NFT, _tokenID){
        require(tokenAuction[_NFT].isOnAuction == false, 'Tokens on auction cannot be listed to direct sell');
        IERC721(_NFT).approve(address(this), _tokenID);
        marketSell[_NFT].isOnSell = true;
        marketSell[_NFT].tokenID = _tokenID;
        marketSell[_NFT].price = _price;
        emit TokenForSell(_NFT, _tokenID);
    }
```

And

```
    function marketBuy(address _NFT, uint _tokenID)  external payable isOwner(_NFT, _tokenID){
        require(msg.value >= marketSell[_NFT].price, 'Less ether then the price');
        IERC721(_NFT).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _tokenID);
        emit TokenSold(_NFT, _tokenID);
    }
```

I control which tokens are on sell through this:

```
struct Market {
        bool isOnSell;
        uint tokenID;
        uint price;
    }

mapping(address => Market) marketSell;
```

Comment: Hello Rodrigo thanks for the answer, I want to know how to get the tokenUri of the ERC721 token of ipfs so that I can show it on the NFT Marketplace?
I don't have the abi of the ERC721 contract, then how can I fetch that?

Comment: The ABI from erc721 you can google easy. The tokenUri is a function from the ERC721. Pass the id of the token as param inside tokenUri().